# Sort a list based on number of votes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to create a new list of a old list that contains all the "Stories" of my site.

Every story contains of several chapters which has a number of votes on them. I want a new list with all stories sorted after the amount of votes.

This is my code so far:

```
def mostVoted
    allStories = Story.all
    allStories.each do |story|
        votes = 0
        story.chapters.each do |chapter|
            votes = votes + chapter.votes.count
        end
    end
end
```

Could someone please help me get further? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you add cumulated vote to Story, and every time you modify chapter.votes recalculate the Story.vote?

Comment: What is your database system?

Comment: When writing Ruby code, we use snake_case for methods and variable names. It's_easier_to_read_snake_case thanItIsToReadCamelCase. So, `mostVoted` should be `most_voted` and `allStories` should be `all_stories`.

Comment: Thank you @theTinMan, I am very new to this. Trying to learn on my own.

Comment: @MrYoshiji: Postgresql

Comment: Since you're using Rails, it's a simple assumption that you're talking about accessing a table using ActiveRecord. Use ActiveRecord to sort the records, don't try to pull the data into Ruby or Rails; Doing that is extremely inefficient and will beat up your server and network as the table grows and will really irritate your DBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def mostVoted
  Story.all.sort_by do |story|
    story.chapters.map do |chapter| 
      chapter.votes.count
    end.reduce(0, :+)
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry this will be a stupid question but how do I use that from a view? My thought was to have create a new list that I can access from my view.

Comment: @yarism While this solution will work as pointed out by theTinMan it is going to create huge n+1 queries probably better to execute this as a grouped query.

Comment: @engineersmnky I agree. If anyone knows how to do this without a N+1 please post!

Comment: I posted a solution I just don't know exactly what he is looking for in the results so i took some liberties in assuming he just wants the "name" which could be title or some other attribute. The OP is a little unclear as to how this is being used so I just posted something very generic.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a query such as

```
Story.joins(:chapters).order("count(chapters.votes)").select("stories.name").group("stories.name")
```

This will help eliminate n + 1 queries associated with the above answers. Not sure what data you are trying to get with this so I took a few liberties.

Answer (score -1):

```
def mostVoted
  Story.all
  .sort_by{|story| story.chapters.inject(0){|n, chapter| n + chapter.votes.count}}
end
```